# How to know which view inside a specific ListView item that was clicked

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm having a `ListView` with my own custom adapter derived from a `BaseAdapter`. Each item in the `ListView` has sub items such as `ImageView` and `TextView`.

How can I know which one of these sub items the user clicked? Is it possible to attach a listener in the `getView` function for example, or could that be a problem?

/ Henrik

Edit: Currently I have a `onItemClick` in the Activity which contains the `ListView`. Is there any good way to know which sub item in a specific item in the ListView which has been pressed by checking the params in the `onItemClick`.

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it. You need to modify your getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View row, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ...     
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;
    if (row == null) {
        row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_row, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper(row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    } else {
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();
    }

    wrapper.yourSubView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   
    {               
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked fine, by problems was I switched to a ImageButton. And that did not work as expected. For others, see this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116583/android-listview-custom-adapter-imagebutton

Answer (score 12):

I used an idea from [Miga's Hobby Programming](http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/).

The key is calling performItemClick() from the new onClick listener. This passes the click on through to the onItemClick() that's already being used for the listview. It's so quick and easy, I feel like I'm cheating.

Here's getView(), from the list adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one_line, parent, false);
    }

    // This chunk added to get textview click to register in Fragment's onItemClick()
    // Had to make position and parent 'final' in method definition
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.someName).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    });
    // do stuff...
}
```

And the onItemClick():

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    long viewId = view.getId();

    if (viewId == R.id.someName) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "someName item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ListView clicked: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
}
```

Comment: clean solution that decouples event propagation from event handling

Answer (score 3):

ListView recycles the row view objects and assigns fresh data on them when "getView" is called, so the approach to use, is to add a listener in the getView function. Here is a code sample from an app that shows how that is done:

```
private class DeletePlayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<Player> data;

        public DeletePlayerAdapter(Context context, int layout,
                ArrayList<Player> list) {
            super(context, layout, list);
            this.layoutResourceId = layout;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = list;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            PlayerHolder holder = null;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                        .getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                holder = new PlayerHolder();
                holder.player_name = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.player_name);
                holder.player_number = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.player_number);
                holder.seeded_button = (ImageButton) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.delete_toggle);
                holder.player_name.setTypeface(tf);
                holder.player_number.setTypeface(tf);
                row.setTag(holder);
                players_array.get(position).marked_for_delete = false;

            } else {
                Log.d("PLAYER_ADAPTER", "NOT_NULL ROW");
                holder = (PlayerHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            holder.seeded_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //
                // Here is the magic sauce that makes it work.
                //
                private int pos = position;

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v;
                    if (b.isSelected()) {
                        b.setSelected(false);
                        players_array.get(pos).marked_for_delete = false;
                    } else {
                        b.setSelected(true);
                        players_array.get(pos).marked_for_delete = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            Player p = data.get(position);
            holder.player_name.setText(p.name);
            holder.player_number.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
            holder.seeded_button
                    .setSelected(players_array.get(position).marked_for_delete);
            return row;
        }

    }

    static class PlayerHolder {
        TextView player_number;
        TextView player_name;
        ImageButton seeded_button;
    }
```

Comment: If I do like this I get the click for that particualar ImageView, but the onItemClick disappears, i.e. the clicking of all other areas of the item (mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);) Is it possible to combine these two without adding a item-listener for all sub-view in that particular item?

Comment: There is no reason you cannot use both approaches. But keep in mind, there is no way to know which child was clicked in itemClicked, because ti just gives you the view and position. So you will get false positives. But it is not too much work to add listeners for the other child views within a row. That is the approach I would suggest, unless the itemSelect function should be called in all cases, including when the area with a clickListener are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only an ImageView and a TextView, you can change your ImageView to ImageButton. You can then add a listener on the ImageButton that will be called if the user clicks on the image. If he clicks anywhere else within the item (including the TextView), the onItemclicklistener will be called.
This is much simpler i think.

Comment: I lost that onItemClickListener-callback, i.e. it isn't called, only the listener for that ImageButton is called

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a generic and reusable solution. Instead of extending a concrete list adapter and modifying the `getView()` method, I created a new class implementing the `ListAdapter` interface that blindly forwards almost everything to another `ListAdapter` except `getView()`. It looks like this:

```
public class SubClickableListAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    public static interface OnSubItemClickListener {
        public void onSubItemClick(View subView, int position);
    }
    private ListAdapter other;

    private SparseArray<OnSubItemClickListener> onClickListeners;

    public SubClickableListAdapter(ListAdapter other) {
        this.other = other;
        onClickListeners = new SparseArray<OnSubItemClickListener>();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(int id, OnSubItemClickListener listener) {
        onClickListeners.put(id, listener);
    }

    public void removeOnClickListener(int id) {
        onClickListeners.remove(id);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = other.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        for(int i = 0; i < onClickListeners.size(); i++) {
            View subView = view.findViewById(onClickListeners.keyAt(i));
            if (subView != null) {
                final OnSubItemClickListener listener = onClickListeners.valueAt(i);
                if (listener != null) {
                    subView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            listener.onSubItemClick(v, position);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    // other implemented methods
}
```

The other implemented methods simply look like the following one:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return other.getItem(position);
}
```

To use it, simply instantiate it supplying any other `ListAdapter` (be it `ArrayAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` or anything else). Then call `setOnClickListener()` for each view where you want to listen on the clicks, giving its id in the `id` parameter, and your listener in the `listener` parameter. To get the row id for the row which was clicked, call the `getItemIdAtPosition(position)` method of your ListView (which you have to get some other way, because it's not given as parameter to your callback, but that shouldn't be a big problem in most cases).

The advantage of this solution is that it can be used with any `ListAdapter`. So if your application has several `ListView`s, each using different underlying views, or even different adapters, you don't have to create a new adapter class for each one.

The problem with this is the same as with all the other solutions: the `OnItemClick()` of the `ListView` won't be called if you click on a view that you registered a listener for. For views that you didn't register a listener, this callback will be called though. So, for example, you have an activity for your list item that contains two text fields and a button, and you register a listener for the button, then clicking on the button won't call the `OnItemClick()` of the `ListView`, but your callback instead. Clicking on anywhere else calls `OnItemClick()`.