# Get JSON Object with onclicklistener on a sub view

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

I have an array adapter populating a listview. The listview is a list of cards as such and these card views contain several subviews (images and strings).

I have a set-up at the minute where I have an onItemClickListener on the listview so that when a card is clicked it gets the JSONObject, packs away some data and launches a new activity.

My question is as follows: is it possible to change this behaviour so that an onClickListener on an image subview of this card can get the JSONObject and launch the new activity or can the JSONObject data only be gotten from the higher-level view.

Comment: yes, you can do onClicklistener of image subView. For more clarification please show us the code.

Comment: Use your onClickListener in adapter class where locate to xml layout and its elements..Use context for intent in adapter calss..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to set an `onClickListener` for the subviews of your `ListView`.

Code example: [How to know which view inside a specific ListView item that was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527101/how-to-know-which-view-inside-a-specific-listview-item-that-was-clicked)