# Get id / position of ListView row

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapterview

I have an Android ListView with a bunch of rows. Each row contains an image and some text. If I click on the image of a row, I want to perform action A, if I click on any other place in the row, I want to perform action B. Both of these actions need the id of the ListView item to work.

So far, for action B, I simply used listview's `onItemClick`, where I got the id from the parameter. However, as far as I know, the only way to find out on which view in  the row itself the user clicked, is to add an `onClick` event handler to the ImageView that triggers action A. In that case, I only get the View that was clicked, though - not the id of the row that the ImageView is in.

My question is - how do I go from a View object to getting the id of the parent row within the ListView?

Comment: Share your code what you have wriiten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onItemClickListener` method has an `onClick interface` already with the `view` and `position` passed into it: You can get check which view has been clicked by doing a `switch` statement and performing a dedicated action when the specific view has been clicked.

E.g.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        String item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this,"You selected : " + item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
    }
});
```

as shown in [How to create listview onItemclicklistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295226/how-to-create-listview-onitemclicklistener)

You'll see that in the `onItemClick` interface it has the `View view` as a parameter and `int position` as a parameter, perform the action inside the listener using both of those parameters. Like i mentioned before you can use a `switch` statement.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            String item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            switch(view.getId()) {
               case R.id.imageView:
                      //perform action for imageView using the data from Item (if you have used an MVC pattern)
               break;
               // you can do this for any widgets you wish to listen for click actions
            }           
        }
    });
```

**Update**: All credit for this goes to wwfloyd in [How to know which view inside a specific ListView item that was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527101/how-to-know-which-view-inside-a-specific-listview-item-that-was-clicked)

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one_line, parent, false);
    }

    // This chunk added to get textview click to register in Fragment's onItemClick()
    // Had to make position and parent 'final' in method definition
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.someName).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    });
    // do stuff...
}
```

in your adapter apply a click listener to the element and then trigger the interface method, so that you can identify the registered widget that has been clicked and then in your `onItemClick` do:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    long viewId = view.getId();
    switch (viewId) {
       case R.id.someName:
            //widget has been clicked
       break;

       default:
           //row has been clicked
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the first idea that came to my mind too, but unfortunately, the View  that is passed as a parameter is not the actual UI element I clicked, but its parent -  the RelativeLayout of the item row.

Comment: That's very strange, you have no click logic on your parent elsewhere?

Comment: No, I simply have a RelativeLayout that has an image view and a few text views. There is no onClick handler on any of the elements

Comment: Oh thanks, that should work! How weird that you have to explicitly register the views to be clickable.

Comment: Happy to help. It is strange, I would suggest using a RecyclerView with your own custom interface in the future, it gets the view that has been registered a listener rather than relying on the whole row.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long id)
```

in this method View arg1 gives you Item view and you can find the item content by this arg1.findViewById(R.id.content);. Here position gives you the item position of list view

Answer (score 1):

if you aren't using tag, then you can

```
int itemId=...;
OnClickListener customOnClick=...;
imageView.setTag(itemId);
imageView.setOnClickListener(customOnClick);
```

and inside your custom `OnClickListener`

```
int itemId = (Integer) view.getTag();
```

note that you can set "any" `Object` as tag, so you may even set your whole custom object, not only id

Answer (score 0):

You can set click listeners for each view in a row from the getView() method in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can impliment it in getView() method of adapter of listview.